# How to add multiple Anonymous Type in c#?

Tags: c#-3.0

Consider this

```
var source = new{  Id = "1", Name = "Name1"}
```

It works fine. But if I want to add 1 more property how to do so...

It failed

```
var source = new{  Id = "1", Name = "Name1"},new{  Id = "1", Name = "Name1"}
```

what is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) and [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) on MSDN:

```
var source = new [] { new {  Id = "1", Name = "Name1"},
                      new {  Id = "2", Name = "Name2"}};
```

Comment: The ending will be "}} and not ")" :)